# Scapy - count number of sniffed packets?

Tags: python, scapy, sniffing

How can I count the number of packets that I have captured using the

```
packets = sniff(filter='udp and host fe80::xx:xx:xx:xx',count=0)
```

function? Is this possible?

I've actually been trying to use prn with this function:

```
def packetCount(packets): 
    global counter 
    counter += 1
```

I have the counter variable defined at the beginning of the program. But I need it to reset to `0` each `sniff()` that I do. Nothing I've tried works though...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sniff` takes couple of parameters you might use.

```
>>> print sniff.__doc__
Sniff packets
sniff([count=0,] [prn=None,] [store=1,] [offline=None,] [lfilter=None,] + L2ListenSocket args) -> list of packets

  count: number of packets to capture. 0 means infinity
  store: wether to store sniffed packets or discard them
    prn: function to apply to each packet. If something is returned,
         it is displayed. Ex:
         ex: prn = lambda x: x.summary()
lfilter: python function applied to each packet to determine
         if further action may be done
         ex: lfilter = lambda x: x.haslayer(Padding)
offline: pcap file to read packets from, instead of sniffing them
timeout: stop sniffing after a given time (default: None)
L2socket: use the provided L2socket
opened_socket: provide an object ready to use .recv() on
stop_filter: python function applied to each packet to determine
             if we have to stop the capture after this packet
             ex: stop_filter = lambda x: x.haslayer(TCP)
```

You might find `timeout` or `count` useful.

Edit: to find the number of packets sniffed, you can use the `len()` function:

```
len(packets)

for i in range(len(packets)):
    print packets[i].summary()

# or better:
for i in packets:
    print i.summary()
```

Comment: I've actually been trying to use prn with this function:

    `def packetCount(packets):
     global counter
     counter += 1`

I have the counter variable defined at the beginning of the program.  But I need it to reset to 0 each sniff() that I do.

Comment: yes prn should work for you, I didn't pay attention to it. Check my update.

Comment: Don't use global variables. Check my solution, using lambdas it can work.

Comment: I don't understand what lambdas are... but ok!  So after the sniff is done, what is the variable holding the length?  x?  or lambda?

Comment: wait... you want to know the number of packets after you stop sniffing?

Comment: `p = sniff(count=100)` if you stop sniffing with CTRL+C you can simply do `len(p)` and it will return the number of packets sniffed.

Comment: Yes.  I guess I'm not being clear.  I am trying to start the sniff, stop the sniff, and then iterate through each packet until it finds the EchoRequest or the UDP packet that I want.  So the problems I've run into is I get an `IndexError: list index out of range` because I iterate to one-too-many packets because I'm looping with a `range(0,x) #statically assigned x`, when I want to loop through `range(0,counter)`.  Does this make sense?

Comment: No need to do all of that... just do `for i in packets: #do stuff` - `i` in this case is 1 packet from all the packets sniffed. So for example `for i in packets: print i.summary()`

Comment: You can also do `for i in range(len(packets)): print packets[i].summary()`

Comment: Ahhhhh the `len(packets)` is what I needed.  I can't believe I didn't think of that!!!  I've been trying to get around this issue for forever.  Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem :) consider accepting and incrementing the answer if you found the answer useful. I'll update my answer.